# Persistent Laravel data filters across multiple views

Tags: laravel-5, filtering, laravel-5.8

I am writing a multi-language dictionary app. When the user selects a language to use data from, that language should apply to every page until they select a different language. Ideally, the language should be part of the URL so that the address for the English word "double" and the French word "double" is different. It should also be possible to specify no language, so that "double" would display both the English and the French word. I will also want to filter the data on multiple fields at the same time, e.g. the word itself and the language.

I'm trying to fit this into the Laravel resource concept. The `index` view of `Word` should show all words filtered by the language, or not filtered if no language is specified. `create` should keep the language from `index`. `store` should just use the form data. The language can be included as a hidden field in the `create` view if it's been specified. `show` doesn't strict speaking need a language filter, but if the user then goes back to `index`, the filter will still need to be applied.

I started using routes, but that means I'll have to hard-code a route for every filter. I've also thought of using session data, but that means the URLs wouldn't include the filter. If the filters are appended as a query string how would Laravel access them? Is this a good solution?

I'm using Laravel 5.8. What's the best Laravel way to persist this type of data filter across views?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues in many areas of  our apps.  We occasionally use `Session` for this, but generally find the most efficient and easiest way to solve this is to attach a database field to the `user` object.

If you are using any type of auth, **Laravel** is already going to boot the `user` object on every page view, thus the filter can be pulled with no extra calls to the database.  If no language is specified, the `\Auth::user()->current_lang_id` will be `null`, and thus no filter would be applied.  We typically use a relationship (e.g. '`currentLang()`') which makes it easy for the user to see the language and can automate binding on the form.

The nice part of this, we've found, is that it individualizes it per user, and it 'remembers' the user's preferences between sessions in a simple way - no need to make dozens of routes or a special variable + logic on multiple routes because those routes include your filter.  Instead, you can put your logic at the top of a base controller and be done with it.

Lastly - changing the language when it is a db field on the user is just standard, simple CRUD.

HTH

Comment: This is potentially good for when a user logs in so that it remembers their settings from last time. However, for sharing links it doesn't work as the second user has to know to select the same language as the first to see the same content. It also doesn't address having multiple filters, since having a field on the user for every potential filter is cumbersome and time consuming in terms of development.

Comment: From the question, I didn't realize those were requirements as well.  The multi filter issue is probably do-able this way with a pivot, and potentially less dev work than creating hard coded routes.  The second user having to know which language -- that is a different, possibly far larger scale issue, and I think might give you a very hard time (n+1 issues, how to display to 2nd user, etc).  Hope you get it solved the way you want it.  If so, stick the answer up for all the issues, it would be interesting to see.